# how to convert a UNION statement into a JOIN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables.

```
Table: Location

  ID   | Name
-------+--------
  1    | Paris
  2    | London
  3    | Sydney

Table: Loc_Map

PrimaryLoc | SecondaryLoc
-----------+-----------
    1      | 3

Table: User

ID  | PrimaryLocID
----+-------------
22  |    1
```

And I want this output, for userID:22.

```
LocationID | LocationName
    1      |    Paris
    3      |    Sydney
```

Please notice that result contains data for both locations IDs which are mapped using the mapping table. I have achieved the desired output using the UNION operator as shown below:

```
SELECT L.id, L.name 
FROM 
    location L 
    INNER JOIN Loc_Map LM ON L.id = LM.PrimaryLoc
    INNER JOIN User U ON U.PrimaryLocID = LM.loc_id
WHERE U.id = 22

UNION

SELECT L.id, L.name
FROM 
    location L INNER JOIN User U ON L.id = U.PrimaryLocID
WHERE U.id = 22
```

For performance enhancement I am trying to convert this SQL query into a JOIN statement but can't. A a single `primaryloc` can have multiple `secondaryloc`s. I tried formatting this question as nicely as possible but please pardon my inexperience in formatting if something looks odd. I also tried hard to come up with a suitable generic question title but couldn't come up other than the given one. If you think of some, please let me know.

I am using SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your sample data, this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.ID LocationID, L.Name LocationName
FROM user u
JOIN loc_map lm ON u.primarylocID = lm.primaryloc
JOIN location l ON l.id = lm.primaryloc 
                OR l.id = lm.secondaryloc
WHERE U.id = 22
```

Comment: Yes, a single `primaryloc` can have multiple `secondarylocs`. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @user1451111 Thanks, updated answer to just include `DISTINCT`

Comment: Can we do it without `DISTINCT`? If yes, any hints to map till the 1X1 level?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just:

```
SELECT L.id, L.name 
FROM 
    location L 
    INNER JOIN Loc_Map LM ON L.id in (LM.PrimaryLoc, LM.SecondaryLoc)
    INNER JOIN User U ON U.PrimaryLocID = LM.loc_id
WHERE U.id = 22
```

note however, that Unions don't "outperform" joins in any general sense.  They are two different things.

Comment: Your answer also works fine but I have to add `DISTINCT` otherwise it fetches the primary location data twice.

Comment: Maybe you need some more join criteria to get to 1x1 mapping?  Note, that your original `UNION` does a distinct sort under the covers (see the execution plan).

Comment: Can you point me to any clues about getting to 1X1 mapping stage?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are only selecting from `location`, `exists` comes to mind before `join`:

```
SELECT L.id, L.name 
FROM location L 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Loc_Map LM INNER JOIN
                   User U
                   ON U.PrimaryLocID = LM.loc_id
              WHERE L.id = LM.PrimaryLoc AND U.id = 22
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM User U 
              WHERE L.id = U.PrimaryLocID AND U.id = 22
             );
```

For performance, you want indexes on `User(PrimaryLocID, id)`, and `Loc_Map(PrimaryLoc, locId)`.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need, no distinct or union required.

```
select
    l.ID LocationID,
    l.Name LocationName
from location l
where
exists
(
    select *
    from Loc_Map lm
    inner join [User] u
    on u.PrimaryLocID = lm.PrimaryLoc
    where
        u.id = 22
        and
        (
            l.id = lm.PrimaryLoc
            or
            l.id = lm.SecondaryLoc
        )
)
```